# mingw error with fopen() in shared folder

Tags: c, windows, mingw, fopen, nas

I have an issue in my C-Project. I'm trying to write an existing file on an nas-server with fopen(name,"w"), but I get an null-pointer. fopen(name,"r") works fine. I have all 
permissions on the server. The thrown error is 22 (invalid argument). Here is my code:

```
fp = fopen("N:\\TEST-DTE\\USER.3\\ROOT\\#DESKTOP", "w");
if(fp)
{
    fprintf(fp, "Hello\n");
    fclose(fp);
}
else
{
    printf("%s\n", strerror(errno));
    fflush(stdout);
}
```

Comment: Is `#DESKTOP` a file or a folder? You probably can't open folders for writing.

Comment: #DESKTOP is a file

Comment: Can you open other files for writing?

Comment: What happens if you rename `#DESKTOP` to `DESKTOP`?

Comment: Can you write to this file with other tools, for example by the command `dir > N:\TEST-DTE\USER.3\ROOT\#DESKTOP`?

Answer (score 0):

I can't write other files.
The filename does not matter.
I can write with other tools, for example with the explorer.
The following solution works:

```
remove("N:\TEST-DTE\USER.3\ROOT\#DESKTOP"); 
fp = fopen("N:\TEST-DTE\USER.3\ROOT\#DESKTOP", "w");
```

But I don't want to do that.

I found the solution. The cause is Kaspersky Antivirus.
If I deactivate Kaspersky, it works!